# Formatting datetime in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm reading time into a variable from a CSV file but some of the time like 9 am is written as 9:00 instead of 09:00. How can I correct it into HH: mm format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`('9:00' -as [datetime]).ToString('HH:mm')`

You can see it working on a loop from 0:00 to 12:00 with this:

```
PS /~> 0..12|%{("$_`:00" -as [datetime]).ToString('HH:mm')}
00:00 
01:00 
02:00 
03:00 
04:00 
05:00 
06:00 
07:00 
08:00 
09:00 
10:00 
11:00 
12:00
```